# Background worker RunWorkerCompleted is firing too late

Tags: c#

I'm using Background Worker i'm having problem with RunWorkerCompleted event he is firing too late. My DoWork method finished all operations and then main therad working, after all operation in main thread RunWorkerCompleted is firing. Is it normal? Should RunkWorkerCompleted not firing after DoWork method. Is it possible to exact RunWorkerCompleted instant DoWork method?

Comment: Please can you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Recording the end time of `DoWork()` and the start time of `RunWorkerCompleted()`is really the only way to know for sure if there is time between these two. How long of a gap is there between `DoWork()` finishing and `RunWorkerCompleted()` starting? I expect your `RunWorkerCompleted()` method is taking longer than you expected.

Comment: _My DoWork method finished all operations and then main therad working, after all operation in main thread RunWorkerCompleted is firing. Is it normal?_ **No**. It always returns after `DoWork` is finished. Either your `DoWork` is taking more time than you anticipated or you are doing stuff in `DoWork` that you are not aware. Without a minimal complete and verifiable example it is not possible to say for sure.

Comment: Difference about time when DoWork() finished and RunWorkerCompleted() started is about 100 milliseconds

Comment: It is not abnormal.  RWC runs on the UI thread, so it entirely depends on how busy that thread might be doing other stuff.  A pretty standard way to cause a delay is by slamming the UI thread with too much work to do by calling ReportProgress or BeginInvoke too often.  The 3rd most common threading bug, after races and deadlocks, a *firehose bug*.  These calls are queued, RWC gets added to the end of the queue, the UI thread tries to empty it.

Comment: So called RWC by me will be a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) states:

> This event is raised when the DoWork event handler returns.

So your method is running longer thn you expect I guess.

You could use `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` and check if method was run successfully.
Documntation also includes how to use it.

Comment: DoWork method finished work and app back to main thread continues call all other lines and after that RunWorkerCompleted is called

Comment: @P.W94 You could try adding something like `MessageBox` with current time, to see if the event was fired right after the method has finished.

Comment: Difference about time when DoWork() finished and RunWorkerCompleted() started is about 100 milliseconds